# ComboBox item imports info to textbox with dataclass

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When I select an item in my combobox I want it to show information from my dataclass into my textboxes, so for instance when I select a customer, it inserts his first name / last name and age.

I had this part:

```
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var customer = from employee in db.employees select employee;
        List<employee> myCustomers = customer.ToList();
        cmbKlant.ItemsSource = myCustomers;
        tbxFirstname.DisplayMemberPath = "firstnaam";
```

But the last part needs to be converted to a string and not show firstname but the actual data, someone knows how to make this work?

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should be using a ViewModel with the MVVM pattern. Have a property there with the customers that you bind the ItemsSource to then have another property for the SelectedCustomer that you bind the selectedItem property of the combobox to which will the always contain the seletced item which you then can bind your textboxes to like SlectedCustomer.Firstname etc.